How can I align a legend symbol above the label in pandas/matplotlib
I'm using a Python visual in Power BI to create a custom Heatmap, and need some help to align the data within the legend. I'm looking to get the symbol aligned above the label, so that it matches what the final product should look like.
I've tried moving the text directly below the symbols with set_x and set_y, which does work, but it does not align well with the entire box
osLegend = fig.legend( labels = ma, loc="center", bbox_to_anchor = (.8, .3),
        ncol = 3, labelspacing = 1, title = "Opportunity Size", markerscale = .5,
        markerfirst = False, columnspacing = .8)

for text in osLegend.get_texts():
    text.set_x(75)
    text.set_y(-30)



Can you share a bit more of code, and some simple test data to make everything reproducible?  (In general, matplotlib's legend have a very rigid structure. You could try to remove the box around the legend, and maybe manually drawing custom box.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
